# Can i use PHPMailer 5.0 version with PHP 7.0

Tags: php, phpmailer, php-7, php-5.3

Currently i am using PHPmailer 5.0 version and PHP Version 5.3 but now i am moving to PHP 7.0.

Can i use phpmailer 5.0 with php 7.0

I need to upgrade to php 7.0 version

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should upgrade to PHPMailer 6.x for PHP 7.x, or you'll get deprecation warnings and possibly errors from the legacy things that PHPMailer 5.x needed for old PHP versions.

Incidentally you should be targeting at least PHP 7.1, preferably 7.2, since [7.0 is already past its end-of-life](https://secure.php.net/supported-versions.php).